# $ git push cloud fatal: remote error: Forbidden

Tags: node.js, git, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-source-repos

**SITUATION:**

I am following this tutorial:

https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/tutorials/bookshelf-on-compute-engine

When I get here:

---

**CODE:**

```
git commit -am "Updating configuration"
git config credential.helper gcloud.sh
git remote add cloud https://source.developers.google.com/p/[YOUR_PROJECT_ID]/
git push cloud
```

---

**ERROR:**

I get the following error:

```
fatal: remote error: Forbidden
```

---

**QUESTION:**

How do I fix this ?

P.S.: I did do: `gcloud auth application-default login`

Comment: What happens when you surf to https://console.cloud.google.com/code/develop/repo?project=[YOUR_PROJECT_ID]? Do you have a repo?

Comment: @csells If I navigate to the link, I do have a repo there.

Comment: Can you use the full URL for the repo:
https://source.developers.google.com/p/[PROJECT]/r/[REPO]

Comment: @csells Yes, I can

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When adding the remote, make sure to use the full URL for your repo, as listed in your set of repositories at https://console.cloud.google.com/code/develop/repo?project=[PROJECT]

For example:

```
git commit -am "Updating configuration"
git config credential.helper gcloud.sh
git remote add cloud https://source.developers.google.com/p/[PROJECT]/r/[REPO]
git push cloud
```

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. But the tutorial mentions:  https://console.cloud.google.com/code/develop/repo?project=[PROJECT] Why ? I would like to understand.

Comment: You've found a bug in our beta product. I've reported it and we'll get it fixed ASAP. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

`gcloud auth application-default login` command acquires user credentials to use for [Application Default Credentials](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials). These credentials are strictly used by Google client libraries in your own application. They are not used for any API calls made by the gcloud CLI or `git-credential-gcloud.sh` script.

Use [`gcloud auth login`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/login) command instead.

Comment: Didn't change anything. I get the exact same error :/